# How to Control relay connected with esp 12e by mqtt

Tags: mqtt, microcontroller, esp8266

Esp12 e connected with pic16f887 Microcontroller.while relay is connected with same esp 12e gpio pin. 
Now, i want to control as well get status of this relay on my android app from anywhere in world.
I want to use MQTT WITHOUT raspberry pi.
How can I do that?

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta I hope that's better ;-)

Answer (score -1):

As per [this](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/2090) answer, you could use your ESP to host an mqtt broker and then use an mqtt app on your android device to control the relay.

**However**, that is a terrible way to do things. There are two alternatives I would reccomend:

- Use a web hosted mqtt server.
- Communicate directly with the ESP with a simple HTTP api.

Without more specifics about your use-case, its difficult to suggest anything more relevant.